# What to do if I cannot find my cat?

Tags: cats, safety, lost-pet

### Introduction to my cat:

I have a 10 months old male cat.
He is almost a pet cat to us. He can enter our home whenever he wants to, but he usually spends most of his time inside our house. He is extremely sleepy, he sleeps almost 12 hours a day.

He was recently trying to find partners for mating.

### My cat is missing:

It has been almost 15 hours since he is not coming to our house. He usually stays in the alley behind ours, he is not even there. The people living there told us that they last saw him around 14 hours ago.

### Request for advice:

I would like to know what can I do to find my cat. This is India, so animal shelters and vets are extremely hard to find.

*I wrote the thing about mating because I thought he could be out there trying to search for potential mates because I have heard that male cats go far in search of potential mates*

Comment: your cat is used to be outdoors so he knows the area if i understand correctly,many young cats can go missing for a few days but as long as they know the area they will come back home even if it takes a couple of days.some cats change owner(find a new home)and there is very little we can do about it

Comment: Not sure when peak mating seasons are in India, but that can be a very good reason for an unfixed male to go missing for a few days, a week or more even. They can pick up females in heat miles away, and will wander much further in search for mates.

Comment: pretty much all you can do is print some flyers and tape them to public noticeboards and things, hoping someone found your cat in their garden and returns him.
And when he does come back, get him castrated...